# Can I use "What's here" function in Google Street View?

Tags: google-maps, street-view

When I use Google maps I get info of the place by "What's here" from right click menu.
But I could not find same function when I use Google Street view.

To get the info I need to enlarge right bottom thumbnail, and move the puppet upside (otherwise the right click menu does not fit my browser size.), and right click the point of puppet, and select "What's here".

Is there easier way to get info when I use Google Street view?
I expect for some kind of extension of Chrome or Firefox.